# Volume of revolution generated by revolving region

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

How can I find the volume of the solid when revolving the region bounded by $y=1-\frac{1}{2}x$, $y=0$, and $x=0$ about the line $ x=-2$? How could I set it up?

Would it be $x=2-2y$
so radius $r(y) = 2-2y -(-2) $ => $r(y)= 4-2y$

$π\int (4-2y)^2 dy$ ?

What would be my limits of integration? Would it be from 0 to 2?

Comment: Are you revolving it around the x-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\textbf{1)}$ Using the disc method, you have $R(y)=(2-2y)-(-2)=4-2y$ and $r(y)=0-(-2)=2$,

so $V\displaystyle=\int_0^1\pi\big((4-2y)^2-2^2\big)dy$.

$\textbf{2)}$ Using the shell method, you have $r(x)=x-(-2)$ and $h(x)=(1-\frac{1}{2}x)-0$,

so $V\displaystyle=\int_0^22\pi(x+2)\big(1-\frac{1}{2}x\big) dx$.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!! YOU ARE THE FIRST PERSON TO ACTUALLY SHOW ME

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad that was helpful.

Comment: why are the limits 0 to 1 on the first one? And what if I wanted to do it about the line x=-1? Would my limits still be the same?

Comment: The y-values in the triangular region being rotated range from 0 to 1.  Rotating about $x=-1$, your limits would remain the same, but you would just subtract -1 instead of -2 in finding R and r.  (For the shell method, the only change would be that $r(x)=x+1$)

Comment: You are the best....

Comment: One more thing, if you have time. What if I wanted to do it about y=1?

Comment: Then the methods would get reversed:  you would use the disc method integrating with respect to x, and the shell method integrating with respect to y.  (The limits for x, or for y, would remain the same, since the region being revolved is still the same.)

Answer (score -1):

First thing you should do is draw a picture of the volume. It looks like a volcano. Then you should decide the shape of the slice you want to use. Either a shell shape or washer shape would work, but not a disk.

For a shell shape, you are integrating dx, and for a washer shape, you are integrating dy. Decide which one you want to use. For a shell, you have to find height and radius. They should be functions of x, no y's in there. For a washer, you have to find inner radius and outer radius. They should be functions of y, no x's.

After you have the dimensions right, THEN you can use your volume formula and integrate.

Comment: Ok, that didn't help. I'm asking people to verify my work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm telling you that you cannot use the disk method. I don't know how bluntly you need it put.

Comment: So how could I do a washer then?

Comment: Very similar to how you are doing already, but you need TWO radii. Then the volume of your slice is $\pi (r_o^2 - r_i^2) dy$.